# Andiodine DNS Tunneling - Connects to server but unable to browse. No internet connectivity

Tags: dns, nexus

I have an **Iodine** (DNS Tunneling) server running on my VPS and have tested and confirmed DNS Tunneling is working by connecting using the Iodine client from my local Linux machine.

When using the **Andiodine** app (https://f-droid.org/packages/org.xapek.andiodine/) on Android however, it connects but i have no internet connectivity.

I've done extensive searching and am unable to work out what the issue is.
My Android device is a Nexus 5 running Android version 6.0.1.
Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any remediations or other things to try?

Comment: you can use an ssh tuunel with iptables mode.

Comment: @kode How? I'm also having a slightly similar issue, only that mine doesn't connect at all but I can DIG the host with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without other steps this is expected. AFAIK your iodine setup only enables the client to send packets to the server, not to any other IP. Internet browsing would require some [configuration](https://gist.github.com/calzoneman/f9d0e5f023026e6a85c9#routing-server) on your VPS.